SharePoint list/agenda reserving a parking space once on a day


SharePoint - I have a reservation list for reserving a parking space. A parking space can only be reserved once on a given day. How can I prevent a parking space from being reserved twice on one day? I don't have a solution for this yet. Thank you for your input.

Please add your question in English language so all community members can understand and you get answers to your question/issue quickly.

I think the only way you can achieve this is by customizing your form in Power Apps and use Power Automate to check for schedule and give result back to your Power App.
